# pip freeze not adding dependencies

Tags: django, heroku, pip, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a django app to heroku and have run into a host of problems. One of them is the fact that when I run pip freeze > requirements.txt I only get wsgi as my dependency, when I know I have several other dependencies. This may also be the reason why my gunicorn is working. Has anyone ran into this problem before?

UPDATE:

I managed to fix this by reinstalling the django toolbelt. Still wondering why that would happen though...

Comment: do you use virtualenv? is your django installed in your system or with virtulenv?

Comment: I'm using virtualenv but I have django installed on both.

Comment: Reinstalling django-toolbelt solved it for me too. You should make this an answer :)